# How to work with real time streaming data/logs using spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am newbie to Spark and Scala.

I want to implement a REAL TIME Spark Consumer which could read the network logs on per minute basis [fetching around 1GB of JSON log lines/minute] from Kafka Publisher and finally store the aggregated values in ElasticSearch.

Aggregations is based on few values [like bytes_in, bytes_out etc] using composite key [like : client MAC, client IP, server MAC, Server IP etc].

Spark Consumer which I have written is:

```
object LogsAnalyzerScalaCS{
    def main(args : Array[String]) {
          val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("LOGS-AGGREGATION")
          sparkConf.set("es.nodes", "my ip address")
          sparkConf.set("es.port", "9200")
          sparkConf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
          sparkConf.set("es.nodes.discovery", "false")

          val elasticResource = "conrec_1min/1minute"
          val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(30))
          val zkQuorum = "my zk quorum IPs:2181"
          val consumerGroupId = "LogsConsumer"
          val topics = "Logs"
          val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_,3)).toMap
          val json = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, consumerGroupId, topicMap)
          val logJSON = json.map(_._2)
          try{
            logJSON.foreachRDD( rdd =>{
              if(!rdd.isEmpty()){
                  val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(rdd.sparkContext)
                  import sqlContext.implicits._
                  val df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
                  val groupedData = 
((df.groupBy("id","start_time_formated","l2_c","l3_c",
"l4_c","l2_s","l3_s","l4_s")).agg(count("f_id") as "total_f", sum("p_out") as "total_p_out",sum("p_in") as "total_p_in",sum("b_out") as "total_b_out",sum("b_in") as "total_b_in", sum("duration") as "total_duration"))
                  val dataForES = groupedData.withColumnRenamed("start_time_formated", "start_time")
                  dataForES.saveToEs(elasticResource)
                  dataForES.show();
                }
              })
             }
          catch{
            case e: Exception => print("Exception has occurred : "+e.getMessage)
          }
          ssc.start()
          ssc.awaitTermination()
        }

object SQLContextSingleton {
    @transient  private var instance: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = _
    def getInstance(sparkContext: SparkContext): org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = {
      if (instance == null) {
        instance = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sparkContext)
      }
      instance
    }
  }
}
```

***First of all I would like to know if at all my approach is correct or not [considering I need 1 min logs aggregation]?***

There seems to be an issue using this code:

1. This Consumer will pull data from the Kafka broker every 30 seconds
   and saving the final aggregation to Elasticsearch for that 30
   sec data, hence increasing the number of rows in Elasticsearch for
   unique key [at least 2 entries per one minute].  UI tool [
   let's say Kibana] needs to do further aggregation. If I increase the
   polling time from 30 sec to 60 sec then it takes a lot of time to
   aggregate and hence not at all remains real time.
2. I want to implement it in such a way that in ElasticSearch only one
   row per key should get saved. Hence I want to perform aggregation
   till the time I am not getting new key values in my dataset which is
   getting pulled from Kafka broker [per minute basis]. After doing
   some googling I have found that this could be achieved using
   groupByKey() and updateStateByKey() functions but I am not able to
   make out how I could use this in my case [should I convert the JSON
   Log lines into a string of log line with flat values and then use
   these functions there]? If I will use these functions then when
   should I save the final aggregated values into ElasticSearch?
3. Is there any other way of achieving it?

Your quick help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Bhupesh

Comment: approach looks good. To improve throughput, could you add more executors to spark?

Comment: Thanks for responding maasg. Could you please confirm on my points which I have listed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object Main {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[*]")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(15))

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "group1",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)//,localhost:9094,localhost:9095"

val topics = Array("test")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)

val out = stream.map(record =>
  record.value
)

val words = out.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val count = words.map(word => (word, 1))
val wdc = count.reduceByKey(_+_)

val sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

wdc.foreachRDD{rdd=>
        val es = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF("word","count")
        import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
        es.saveToEs("wordcount/testing")
  es.show()
}

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()

 }
}
```

[To see full example and sbt](https://github.com/ashanchameera/kafka-spark-elasticsearch.git)

[apache-spark](/questions/tagged/apache-spark)[scala](/questions/tagged/scala)[hadoop](/questions/tagged/hadoop)[kafka](/questions/tagged/kafka)[apache-spark-sql](/questions/tagged/apache-spark-sql) [spark-streaming](/questions/tagged/spark-streaming)[apache-spark-2.0](/questions/tagged/apache-spark-2.0)[elastic](/questions/tagged/elastic)